# GeoCoding in Rails for polygon bounds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, geocoding

Is there a way in rails via some mapping API/gem where I can define map areas/map zones (with polygon bounds) and detect if an address falls within a particular zone/area.

Comment: I feel that this should have just been migrated to [Software Recomendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead of closed. Also, it's not too broad.  The answer would be "use geokit.  Here's a code example of how you would use it."  Exactly as seen below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is easily done with [geokit](https://github.com/geokit/geokit).

First construct a polygon from LatLng:

```
polygon = Geokit::Polygon.new([ 
  Geokit::LatLng.new(0,0), 
  Geokit::LatLng.new(10,0), 
  Geokit::LatLng.new(10,10), 
  Geokit::LatLng.new(20,10), 
  Geokit::LatLng.new(20,0), 
  Geokit::LatLng.new(30,0), 
  Geokit::LatLng.new(30,20), 
  Geokit::LatLng.new(0,20)
])
```

Then you can test if the polygon contains a LatLng:

```
point = Geokit::LatLng.new(5,5)

polygon.contains?(point) # => true
```

Comment: contains? is Bounds method.
Can't work with an array.

But Bounds represents a rectangular bounds, defined by the SW and NE corners.

Comment: Corrected the code. I forgot to add the `Geokit::Polygon.new`. Polygon also supports `contains?`

Comment: Wauw this is awesomeness! Thanks

Comment: @infused Does this method work if I  give polyline points instead of polygone points? I tried to read the docs of geokit and geokit rails gem, but couldn't find much on how the gem creates polygon.

Comment: Awesome answer! This info is hard to find anywhere. It works great.