# Get all points that lies within a polygon on Google Map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, rails-geocoder

I am building a Rails Application in which Google map is used for filtering all points on map with drawing tools
File Model.rb

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  geocoded_by :address, :latitude  => :lat, :longitude => :lng

  def address
   [city, state].compact.join(', ')
  end
end
```

controller.rb

```
def in_bounds
 unless params[:polygon].nil?
   poly = params[:polygon].split('),(').map{|k| k = k.gsub(/[()]/, "")}
   all_points = []
   poly.each do |p|
    all_points.push (p.split(',').collect(&:strip).map{ |k| k = k.to_f})
   end


   render json: all_points
   return
 end
end
```

Output

> [
>   [
>   44.24519901522129,
>   -77.36572265625
>   ],
>   [
>   42.84375132629021,
>   -69.27978515625
>   ],
>   [
>   34.488447837809304,
>   -67.87353515625
>   ],
>   [
>   36.06686213257888,
>   -81.76025390625
>   ],
>   [
>   42.58544425738491,
>   -81.93603515625
>   ]
>   ]

How to find all points that lies within these specific co-ordinates
I am using this [gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275459/2797929) 
Kindly use [Geokit Gem](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails)